# Distorted plot when I plot Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2] and -Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2 together

Tags: plotting, graphics

[image: here the question]

When I plot `Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]` and `-Sqrt[4 - x^2 - y^2]` together,the `z` axis doesn't have the same ticks as `x` and `y` axis. How can I make *Mathematica* show its real shape?

Comment: You are likely looking for the `BoxRatios` option.

Comment: Use `BoxRatios -> Automatic`